# Is there any time where I should prefer a stateful API over stateless?

Tags: rest

If I set up the route to the user's "Edit Contact Info" page it could forexample either look like this:

```
'/account/{id}/contactinfo'
```

Or it could look like this:

```
'/account/contactinfo'
```

and in the second case I can fetch the user's id myself and return the user specific response. On a quick analysis I end up deciding that the second option is better for **some cases** such as one mentioned above. because, at the very least I'd have less authorization checks to run on the latter route .(Or an entire route group with an `account/` prefix).

The question is will I be missing something if I went with the latter? what General REST API benefits may I potentially lose with this approach? Or is it beneficial to always stick with statelessness on the long run? The long run is what I'm always interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want current user information and not other users' information, then second way is better. And in a way it is more secure, by not exposing data that is not required. And also in the client side it saves from saving user_id in local-storage or some services.

Comment: hmm. ya that's what I've been thinking mostly. to seperate a ```users/{id}/info``` where is accessible for everybody from ```account/contanctinfo``` where it's all about setting account preferences.